# ( ! ) Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated

Tags: php, cakephp, app-config, mit-scratch

( ! ) Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in E:\wamp\www\Scratch\cake\basics.php on line 1101

Hi All, 
I am new to cake php . I am trying to configure the scratch application in my local system . 
After following the few steps in URL http://svn.assembla.com/svn/scratchr/INSTALL.txt. then launch the application in local it is showing the above error. I am not getting where it went wrong.

Could you please tell me how to configure this scratch application in local system (windows 7) or how to get rid of the above error

Comment: maybe you are running a new version of PHP and some the codes has been deprecated. Did the error stopped the application or it was just a warning ?

Comment: @iamsleepy:- how to find the version of the php used in the application???

Comment: try to look within the files, readme. Usually developers will state the php version they built the application on.

Comment: or try to locate what was on `line 1101` in basics.php and search for it in the php manual. See if the function was deprecated.

Comment: @iamsleepy:- $folder =& new Folder(APP.'plugins'.DS);
      $plugins = $folder->ls(); these are the two lines.. iam using php 5

Comment: Sorry, did the application stopped by the error or you just want to get rid of the errors ? For the latter case you can set `error_reporting(0);`